# SSH problem after update

Tags: ssh, openssh

```
Setting up openssh-server (1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) ... 
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ... 
Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ... 
start: Job failed to start
```

Can't initialize ssh, already tried reinstall.

SSH server is started manually via `/etc/init.d/ssh start`

`netstat -nlp` shows that no services are running at TCP port 22

Comment: Could you clarify in your question if you have tried starting it manually, ie `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start`, and if so, did it give a different error than when you installed? Also, maybe you would want to install `nmap` and run `nmap 127.0.0.1` to see if there is already a instance of ssh running and put the result in your question.

Comment: i tried to run it manually, and got the same thing

Comment: Try to start once again the ssh daemon manually and then open `/var/log/auth` and check at the bottom of the file what the logs show...

Answer (score 19):

Not sure that my solution is right. But if you just want to start your SSH server and then solve your problem later, here is my fast solution:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- -p 22
```

if then you will see error:

```
Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd
```

then just create that missing directory, and try above start-stop-daemon command again:

```
mkdir /var/run/sshd
chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd
```

that helped me to start my sshd daemon.

Comment: This only fixes it for the current session. After a reboot that directory will be gone.

Comment: in the file /etc/init/ssh.conf add in the section pre-start script the folowing line :" mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem that `sshd` would not start because of error.
It showed that there was no directory `/var/run/sshd`.

```
ll  /var/run
```

showed a link to `/run`.
But on my system `/run` runs on ramdisk.
So I deleted the link and created the directories `/var/run` and `/var/run/sshd`. Now the `sshd` starts normally and I am able to reach my system over `ssh` again.

Answer (score 1):

reconfiguring my firewall to allow port 22 worked for me.

```
ufw enable
ufw allow 22
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 3 issues resulting in this behavior (for my system Ubuntu 14.04LTS):

1- ssh unknown job occurs when you try to use 'service ssh start' from a 'su'
session. Solution is to use sudo service start from a logged in user that can 'sudo'

2- The existing init.d/ssh script is exiting quietly without actually starting sshd when ssh is on upstart

3- The main reason ssh does not start is because on Ubuntu 14.04 there is an empty file
/etc/ssh/sshd_host_not_to_run which indicates that sshd should not run. Just delete that file if you want sshd to run.

So overall solution is: Use sudo service ssh start after deleting /etc/ssh/sshd_host_not_to_run

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug report with a non-kluge solution to this bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1811580

***can be defused by implicitly setting 'UsePrivilegeSeparation no' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config,***

re-installing doesn't necessarily fix it.