# Unable to SSH into server after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vps

I just upgraded the server from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and now I am unable to SSH into the server.
Any ideas? I'm using Putty on Windows 10.

Edit:
Whenever I finish the update and restart the machine. Then Putty prompt ends, saying the connection closed normally.
If I try to log on again I get the error message over and over again saying: “Server unexpectedly closed network connection”.
I can ping the server.
I can reboot the server via my provider but this those not help the problem.

Comment: There is any error message ? You just can't reach your server ? Can you ping it ? We cannot help you without additionnal informations. Please update your question.

Comment: Check your syslog (`/var/log/syslog` on your ubuntu server) for error messages.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: I cannot access Ubuntu at all.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Does the (virtual) machine boot at all? If so, what's the output of `sudo systemctl start ssh.service; sudo systemctl status ssh.service`?

Comment: I think this was a great question, and should be reopened. When you upgrade a VPS to 18.04 and after a reboot you cannot SSH in, you don't have a lot of clues to go on. I am going to post my experience here for the next poor unfortunate soul.

Comment: posted my fix here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037131/lost-ssh-access-after-upgrade-to-18-04/1065319#1065319

Answer (score -2):

Check your ssh settings on server, usually what happens in that after upgrade ssh service stops running so you have to re-enable it manually.

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Comment: And how are you supposed to do that if you can't ssh into the server?

Comment: @DevOpsSauce that is a very good question, I was in luck and had physical access, so logged in and restored the service. Not sure why do I get so many dislikes, it did solve the issue for me.